# How to make a div slide with scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to make a div slide (in,out,left,up,right or down) when I reach a specific scrollTop() value. However, I don't want it to trigger some animation... I want the div to move with the scroll, like the effect achieved here: http://www.tioluchin.com/

so far, the "closest" I got was this:

```
var vistaEstandar = document.getElementById('vista');
vistaEstandar.onscroll = function() {animacionesEstandarVista()};
    function animacionesEstandarVista() 
    {
        var ypos  = vistaEstandar.scrollTop;

        if (($(window).width() >= 1800 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop > 6053) || ($(window).width() > 1800 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 6053)) {
            var image= document.getElementById("seccion9textoSegundo");
            var toppin = ypos/6053;
            image.style.top = toppin*150 + 'px';
        }
        else
        {};
```

However, this doesn't work because the value I manage to set is too low.

The web I am trying to put together is long so when I multiply the value it is either too high or too low.

In the website http://www.tioluchin.com/  I want the effect the knives and food have

Comment: https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: thanks, Rachel.. but that plugin, for what I can see... It's to modify the scrollbar. I want is to animate an image or div to slide a pixels in proportion to the scrollTop value

Comment: it's in use on the website you referred to

Comment: yes, but I mean the effect of the knives and food, which move when scrolling, let me add it to the question!! thanks for putting that out

Comment: inspect the source of the website.. its the easiest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into that source code because it made me curious. I have found how they do it.

First part is catching what happens on scroll

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    windowScroll()
});
```

They have there a condition which disables it on smaller screens but that is not important here.

Second part is this:

```
 function windowScroll(){
  var st = $(document).scrollTop();

  $("#aff").css({"top": 32 - st * 0.15 + "px"});
  $("#aff").css({"left": 48 - st * 0.15 + "px"});
 }
```

They have it bigger, for more elements. And this is my playground. In principle you have start with current position as an offset. "st" indicates how deep you are. st*0.15 tells you how fast the element will run from the screen.

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="aff" class="moving-div">

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
 .moving-div {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 3rem;
    background: red;
  }

  .wrapper {
    height: 1000px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... now that added a value and then the -st*0.15 it works. Thanks a lot, Sarah!